# пожалуйста помоги с решением задачи по работе со списком Python

Tags: python

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    len_arr = len(arr)
    for i in range(len_arr):
        if sum(arr[:i]) == sum(arr[i:]) and sum(arr[:i]) != None and sum(arr[i:]) != None:
            break
        return i
```

Не могу понять как обойти в цикле проверку, при которой не получим результат среза `sum(arr[i:]) == 0`, и как сделать срез в этом случае в цикле?

вот условия задачи:

> You are going to be given an array of integers. Your job is to take
> that array and find an index N where the sum of the integers to the
> left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If
> there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.
>
> For example:
>
> Let's say you are given the array {1,2,3,4,3,2,1}: Your function will
> return the index 3, because at the 3rd position of the array, the sum
> of left side of the index ({1,2,3}) and the sum of the right side of
> the index ({3,2,1}) both equal 6.
>
> Let's look at another one. You are given the array {1,100,50,-51,1,1}:
> Your function will return the index 1, because at the 1st position of
> the array, the sum of left side of the index ({1}) and the sum of the
> right side of the index ({50,-51,1,1}) both equal 1.
>
> Last one: You are given the array {20,10,-80,10,10,15,35} At index 0
> the left side is {} The right side is {10,-80,10,10,15,35} They both
> are equal to 0 when added. (Empty arrays are equal to 0 in this
> problem) Index 0 is the place where the left side and right side are
> equal.
>
> Note: Please remember that in most programming/scripting languages the
> index of an array starts at 0.
>
> Input: An integer array of length 0 < arr < 1000. The numbers in the
> array can be any integer positive or negative.
>
> Output: The lowest index N where the side to the left of N is equal to
> the side to the right of N. If you do not find an index that fits
> these rules, then you will return -1.
>
> Note: If you are given an array with multiple answers, return the
> lowest correct index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этого кода достаточно:

```
def check_arr(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if sum(arr[:i])==sum(arr[i+1:]):
            return i
    return -1

assert check_arr([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])==3
assert check_arr([1, 100, 50, -51, 1, 1])==1
assert check_arr([20, 10, -80, 10, 10, 15, 35])==0
```

Comment: Проще простого оказалось спасибо... как то застрял на этом